# Include help in an excel add-in

Tags: vba, excel, add-in

I have a .xlam file that adds some menu options to excel. I would like to add help to the add-in, but cannot seem to find an elegant solution to do so. Here's the options I have tried:

**MsgBox:**
Add a drop-down menu where each item launches a message box. This does not work well because there is a limit to how much text can be displayed in a message box. My help would need to be longer, so it truncates it.

**UserForm:**
Add a user form to display the help in a text box that is locked. This allows me to display longer text with a scroll bar and also allows the users to copy sections of the text. The problem is, because my Add-in is Protected and I have checked "Lock project for viewing", whenever a user opens this form and later closes excel, it prompts for the Add-in password. I have checked this website and google and there does not seem to be a viable solution for this issue.

My question is: What alternatives are available to me to display help for the Add-in?

Comment: @chrisneilsen, thanks for the suggestion, but this requires that each user must also have the `.chm` file on their machine instead of just the `.xlam` file. I'm looking for something that can be embedded so that my Add-in remains only one file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this by embedding a pdf file in 'This_Workbook' as an OLE Object and used VBA to trigger its opening via the following VBA code:

The OLE pdf was named `objPDF`:

```
Public Function getPdfReference() As OLEObject   
    Set getPdfReference = Worksheets("Plan1").OLEObjects.Item("objPDF")    
End Function
```

and the module that calls the file uses this function

```
Public Sub openPDF()
    Dim obj As OLEObject
    Set obj = This_Workbook.getPdfReference()    
    obj.Activate 'opens the PDF file
End Sub
```

This way, the PDF goes along within the add-in, in a hidden manner, and when someone clicks on a help button you may call `openPDF()` and a PDF pops out. I think this is more elegant than deploying a separated file.

Answer (score 2):

I use a .chm file located in the same folder as the XLAM. 
Called from VBA using Application.Help

```
Application.Help ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & gstrHelpFile, jContextid
```